# Matrix Error in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm writing a function in R to take a number and perform an operation on every row of the matrix. Each matrix should have 50 elements, `ncol(x)` is 50. Here's the calculation I'm performing

```
function(v1,v2){
 a <- sum(v1*v2)
 b <- sqrt(sum(v1*v1))* sqrt(sum(v2*v2))
return(a/b)
}
```

Here's a sample of my data:

```
the 0.41800  0.249680 -0.41242  0.121700 0.345270 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.178620 -0.00066023 -0.656600 0.278430 -0.14767 -0.55677  0.14658 -0.0095095
. 0.15164  0.301770 -0.16763  0.176840 0.317190  0.339730 -0.43478 -0.310860 -0.44999000 -0.294860 0.166080  0.11963 -0.41328 -0.42353  0.5986800
of  0.70853  0.570880 -0.47160  0.180480 0.544490  0.726030  0.18157 -0.523930    0.10381000 -0.175660 0.078852 -0.36216 -0.11829 -0.83336  0.1191700
to  0.68047 -0.039263  0.30186 -0.177920 0.429620  0.032246 -0.41376  0.132280 -0.29847000 -0.085253 0.171180  0.22419 -0.10046 -0.43653  0.3341800
and 0.26818  0.143460 -0.27877  0.016257 0.113840  0.699230 -0.51332 -0.473680 -0.33075000 -0.138340 0.270200  0.30938 -0.45012 -0.41270 -0.0993200
in  0.33042  0.249950 -0.60874  0.109230 0.036372  0.151000 -0.55083 -0.074239 -0.09230700 -0.328210 0.095980 -0.82269 -0.36717 -0.67009  0.4290900`
```

Here's what I'm trying to write, it's pretty straightforward:

```
function(w,m) {
 r=matrix(nrow=nrow(m),ncol=2)
 for(i in 1:(nrow(m)-1)) {
 r[i,1]=cosineSim(m[w,],m[i,])
}
 r=sort(r,decending=TRUE)
 return (r)
}
```

1)Create a new matrix with the same columns and rows as matrix m. 
2)Loop through m-1 rows. 
3)Each row, use `cosineSim` to compute the cosine similarity of the current vector (row) of the loop.
4)Once the end of the loop is finished, sort and return `r` which is the array holding the result.

The problem is that the algorithm seems to enter an infinite loop.

I need this to work for a project and would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Vectors in R start at 1 not 0.

Comment: Thank you so much, however now my problem now seems to be that it enters an infinite loop, I'm not entirely sure it's not running, I'm working with 20M elements but I have a fairly decent laptop and it's been running for several minutes. I will update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of TMin, I was able to realize the problem in my code. Also I figured out that it's not stuck in an infinite loop, rather scanning ~20M elements and taking a long time doing it.